# Java getting userinput from the user

Tags: java, printing, input, java.util.scanner, system.out

```
import java.util.List;

import ShortHand.utilities.CollectionCreation;

public class MultipleChoice<Q,A,C>
{
    Q question;
    A answer;
    C choices;

    public MultipleChoice(Q q, A a, C c){
        question = q;
        answer = a;
        choices = c;
    }

    public Q getQuestion(){ return question;  }
    public A getAnswer(){ return answer;  }
    public C getChoices(){ return choices;  }

    public void addChoices(C c ){ choices = c; }
    public void addQuestion(Q q){ question = q; }
    public void addAnswer(A a){ answer = a; }

    public String toString(){
         return "Question: "+this.getQuestion()+ "\n"+
                "Choices: "+this.getChoices();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        List<MultipleChoice<String,String,String>> mc = CollectionCreation.list();
        int numOfQuestions;
        System.out.print("Enter number of Question: ");
        numOfQuestions = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i< numOfQuestions; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Question: ");
            String question = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter choices: ");
            String choices = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Answer: ");
            String answer = input.nextLine();
            mc.add(new MultipleChoice(question,choices,answer));
        }

        for(MultipleChoice<String, String, String> items : mc)
            System.out.println(items+"\n");

    }
}
```

My problem here is that when the loop started I can't seem to input in the The question itself under the "Enter your Question" and same goes for others. any idea why?

What I am expecting is that the once  I click enter it would go to "Enter The choices".

But it seems they're printing at the same time therefore rendering me to unable to answer the "Enter your question" should I fix this?

CollectionCreation is just returning an arrayList() using type inference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse you're reading from `System.in`, the Scanner won't get any input until you hit enter. Thus when you read only an int using `nextInt()`, there's an extra newline in the buffer that isn't read, and it gets instantly read in the next `input.nextLine()` call (which will be an empty String.

Try changing the nextInt() to nextLine():

```
numOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine().trim());
```

Alternatively, you can `reset()` the scanner after the `nextInt()` call.

Comment: I tried doing this  numOfQuestions = Integer.parseInt(input.nextInt().trim()); but it is still not working

Comment: @user962206 sorry, typo. Should be nextLine()